# Solving BPV of second order nonlinear ODE through NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-value

I'm trying to solve a 2nd order related ODE system in two region using Piecewise. BC: 1) `y'[0]`=0 and at `y'[1.6]=0` while at 1 `y'[1] is continues.`y[1.6]=0`and`y[0]= y0.

I'm using to use NDSolve as shown below, but the code did not solve the system

How could I write code using NDSolve that the solution match at `y'[1] in the two region?
The code is:

```
 \[Epsilon] = $MachineEpsilon ;
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{2.7, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0, 1 < x <= 1.6}}];
s = NDSolve[{y''[x] + 2 y'[x]/x == - Cosh[-y[x]] + f[x], 
   y[1] == y0, y'[\[Epsilon]] == 0}, y, {x, \[Epsilon], 1.6},
   Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", WorkingPrecision -> 40]
Plot[%, {x, 0, 1.6}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

Comment: You write `y[\[Epsilon]] == y0,` but there is no `y0` in your code. it will be better to make the code self contained so it it easy to copy and paste it in one copy.

Comment: `y0` is the value of function at `\[Epsilon]`that need to evaluate.

Comment: `y0 is the value of function at \[Epsilon]that need to evaluate` I am not following. You are giving an initial condition for the dependent variable at some location as unknown? This is `NDSolve` not `DSolve`. So I think it should be known value there.

Comment: Ok. ODE has to region, and my goals to solve ode in each region and match the solution at Y(1). So, how could I do this?

Comment: Moreover, I need to pass an initial estimate to the function at x=1, and from that using find root. But I did know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Plot[{Piecewise[{{2.7, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0, 1 < x <= 1.6}}], 
  2.7/(1 + Exp[200 (x - 1)])}, {x, 0, 1.6}]
```

[image]

```
\[Epsilon] = $MachineEpsilon;
f[x_] := 2.7/(1 + Exp[200 (x - 1)]);
s[c_] := y /. 
   First@NDSolve[{y''[x] + 2 y'[x]/x == c*-Cosh[-y[x]] + f[x], 
      y[1.6] == 0, y'[\[Epsilon]] == 0}, y, {x, \[Epsilon], 1.6}, 
     Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", AccuracyGoal -> 30];
sol = s[1];
Plot[sol[x], {x, 0, 1.6}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

---

With variable parameter `c`,

```
Do[
  sols[i] = s[i];, {i, 0, 1, 0.1}];

Plot[MapThread[sols[#][x] &, {Range[0, 1, 0.1]}], {x, 0, 1.6}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

With `Manipulate`

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[sols[c][x], {x, 0, 1.6}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}], {c, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: let say I have a parameter `c` `y''[x] + 2 y'[x]/x == -Cosh[-y[x]] + f[x]` > `y''[x] + 2 y'[x]/x == -c Cosh[-y[x]] + f[x]` ?How to insert it in your NDSolve method ?

Comment: @user66021 would you ask/post it as another(new) question?

Comment: Is it worth to put a new questions since I'm just adding a parameter. ?

Comment: @user66021 ok,I've understand what you mean from [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200110/solving-bpv-of-second-order-nonlinear-ode-through-ndsolve#comment517882_200123).

Comment: Yes, Would you please do it in NDSolve?

Comment: @user66021 we have already do it in NDSolve. Try with `s[c]`,where `c` is the parameter.

Comment: Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your problem using `ParametricNDSolve`.

Because MMA currently (v 11.0.1) isn't able to solve boundary value problems I define an initial value problem at the boundary `x=1.6` with unknown slope `y'[1.6]==ys1` thereby avoiding the singularity at `x==0`

```
Y = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[x] + 2 y'[x]/x == -Cosh[-y[x]] + f[x], y[1.6] == 0, y'[1.6] == ys1}, y, {x, 0, 1.6}, {ys1}]
```

Now try to find `ys1` such that `y'[0]->0`

```
opt = NMinimize[{1, Y[ys1]'[0] == 0 , -.5 < ys1 < 0}, {ys1}]
Plot[Y[ys1][x] /. opt[[2]] , {x, 0, 1.6}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

In this approach there is no need to introduce small  `\[Epsilon]`, special method (NDSolve), very high WorkingPrecision or simplified `f[x]`

Comment: Thanks for those solutions. What will happen if `y''[x] + 2 y'[x]/x == -Cosh[-y[x]] + f[x]` has a parameter (c)  > `y''[x] + 2 y'[x]/x == -c Cosh[-y[x]] + f[x]` ?How to insert it in NDSolve method ?

Comment: `ParametricNDSolveValue[..., {ys1,c}] `

Comment: Thanks @Ulrich Neumann.